# Unable to inject dependency in fragment using hilt

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-hilt

I have a fragment class as follows:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.main_fragment) {

    @Inject lateinit var runner: Runner

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        runner.runProcess()
    }
}
```

Here is my Runner.java file:

```
public class Runner {

    @Inject
    public Runner(@ApplicationContext Context applicationContext) {
        // some setup code
    }

    public runProcess() {...}
}
```

I am getting an error at the *runner.runProcess()* line saying that *lateinit property runner is not initialized*. I am using Hilt in my Android app. How can I go about fixing this?

MainActivity.kt:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity @Inject constructor() : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<MainFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is defined the Runner to be provided with annotation @Provides?

Comment: @RuiAlves sorry, updated the code. I am trying to inject the Runner class directly.

Comment: Since it's not showing in your code, just checking, have you added `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation before your fragment class declaration `class MainFragment` ?

Comment: Do note that "Hilt only supports fragments that extend the Jetpack library Fragment, not the Fragment from the Android platform." as mentioned here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#4

Comment: @Ankur yes I have extended it from the Jetpack library fragment.

The ```@AndroidEntryPoint``` is added in my ```MainActivity``` as updated.

Comment: I have also added the ```@HiltAndroid``` app annotation in my application class and the corresponding android:name parameter in the manifest as shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#application-class

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I have to add the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation to my fragment as well, despite the fragment being added to the main activity which has this annotation.

For future reference, the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation should be provided for every android class which requires dependency injection. It marks the entry points for hilt to inject modules. It is not to be confused with the entry point of the app i.e., the launch activity.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#android-classes)